# How do I restart google cloud service in shell?

Tags: apache, debian, cloud

I have created a virtual instance in Google Cloud and updated php.ini. I need to restart the server for the changes to take place, but every command I've tried has failed:

- service php5-fpm restart
- sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
- service apache2 restart
- /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Any suggestions?

Settings:

Operating system: Debian 9

Package contents:

- Apache 2.4.33
- ImageMagick 6.9.8
- MySQL 5.7.22
- OpenSSL 1.0.2o
- PHP 7.0.30
- phpMyAdmin 4.8.0.1
- SQLite 3.18.0
- Varnish 4.1.0
- WordPress 4.9.5
- WP-CLI 1.5.1

Answer (score 2):

You need to restart web server, this case it is apache

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Answer (score 1):

To restart the server you can use

```
"shutdown -r now" 
Or
"/sbin/shutdown -r now"
```

Make sure you are login in root account.